# HL7 text message, how to find the specific field information

Tags: c#, hl7

```
MSH|^~\&|A|B|C|D|201402141402||ORM^O01|33987|D|2.3
PID|1|99989392|99989392||UHCMCDO^TWO^^^^||19810101|M|||5678 CANDY CANE LANE^^EUCLID^OH^44117^UNITED STATES||(212)353-6048|(212)323-6078||||99576837||||NonHispan||||||||N
PV1|1|O|320|R|C||49762^Abouassaly^Robert||||||||||||99576837||||||||||Y|||||||||||||||201402141402||||||A49417331
IN1|1|43||MEDICAID-OH: CUYAHOGA COUNTY DEPT OF CHILDREN & FAMILY SERVICES|3955 EUCLID AVE^^CLEVELAND^OH^44115-2505||(216)431-4500|||||||||UHCMCDO^TWO^|S|||||1||||||||||||||123456789001|||||||M
GT1|1||UHCMCDO^TWO^^^||5678 CANDY CANE LANE^^EUCLID^OH^44117|(212) 353-6048||19810101|||S
ORC|NW||||||||20140214140256
OBR|1|36358||GC1^Non GYN - Cytology|R||201403281402||||||||NONGYNC^Non GYN - Cytology|49762^Abouassaly^Robert|||||||||||^^^^^R
DG1|1|I9|V70.0|ROUTINE MEDICAL EXAM - V70.0
OBX|1|TX|PTH_SITE1^Site A|1|left||||||F|||||||
OBX|2|TX|PTH_SPEC1^Specimen A||C-FNA^Fine Needle Aspiration||||||F|||||||
```

I have a HL7 files which I need to get on to the PID segment to get patient name "UHCMCDO^TWO^^^^ and then I need to traverse to OBR segment to get the  Order ID 36358 and then submit to database table.
I tired finding the PID then going to 5th field to get the Patient Name but cannot.

I know how to search by specific value, not with dynamic changing values but I have 100s of file and I need to get each patient name and their Order id to pull a report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file format is always the same, you can use regular expressions to get the data you're looking for.

```
string name = Regex.Match(inputString,@"^PID([\d\|]*)\|\|(.*?)\|\|").Groups[2].Value;
string obrId = Regex.Match(inputString,@"OBR\|[\d]*\|(\d*)\|").Groups[1].Value;
```

where the first is looking for the first match for something between double pipes after PID,
and the second is looking for the second number between pipes.

If the format of the files isn't consistent though, this will not work.

Edit:
Here's a bit of code I ran at ideone.com (http://ideone.com/0HROlL) using your sample as the "raw" string

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string raw = @""; //Paste text here, new lines and all
        string[] lines = raw.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },  StringSplitOptions.None); 
        string name = "";
        string obrId = "";
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("PID"))
            {
                name = Regex.Match(line,@"^PID([\|]*[^\|]*){3}[\|]*([^\|]*)").Groups[2].Value;
            }
            else if (line.Contains("OBR"))
            {
                obrId = Regex.Match(line,@"OBR\|[\d]*\|(\d*)\|").Groups[1].Value;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(obrId);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
UHCMCDO^TWO^^^^
36358
```

Comment: The double pipes in PID may or may not be having data...can we specifically look for 5th position in PID or any other way to get that position. Thank you for guiding me here. I don't have good experience in REGEX

Comment: Sure, by 5th position, are the previous four guaranteed to be there? If so, something like @"^PID([\|]*[^\|]*){3}[\|]*([^\|]*)" should work. which looks for the pattern of "any number of pipes followed by any number of non-pipes", and looks for the 4th (excluding PID)

Comment: Hi David, I'm trying to run my app following the regex you provided but it doesn't pick anything from both the regex ....can you please help me again with this.

Comment: Added example code to the answer; regex isn't the most intuitive to debug, sqlab's answer may be a better long term solution, if third party libraries are an option.

Comment: Thanks David it is working now :) I just removed the carrot sign from PID. Thanks a lot. but I need to learn how regex was developed like that so I can make further field into my report similarly. If you have something nice which can assist me pls send it to vijay.baswal@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

[An example for HL7 parsing in C#](http://www.j4jayant.com/articles/hl7/31-hl7-parsing-lib) with nHapi .
You will find nHapi [here](http://nhapi.codeplex.com/) or [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhapi/)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ based solution - sample usage:

```
var fields = Field.Parse(hl7);
var name = fields.First(Field.Locate("PID:5")).Value;
var order = fields.First(Field.Locate("OBR:2")).Value;
```

where Field class is:

```
public class Field
{
    public int SegmentSequence { get; set; }
    public string SegmentId { get; set; }
    public int FieldIndex { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static IList<Field> Parse(string hl7, string segmentDelimiter = "\r")
    {
        if(hl7 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("hl7");
        if(hl7.Length < 4) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid HL7 syntax.");
        hl7 = hl7.Replace("\r\n", "\r");
        try
        {
            var fieldDelimiter = hl7[3];
            return hl7.Split(new string[] { segmentDelimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Where (s => s.Length > 0)
                .SelectMany(
                    (s, i) => s.Split(fieldDelimiter)
                                .Select(
                                    (f, j) => new Field { 
                                                    SegmentSequence = i, 
                                                    SegmentId = s.Substring(0,3), 
                                                    FieldIndex = i==0 ? j+1 : j, 
                                                    Value = f
                                                }
                                        )
                ).Where(o => !(o.FieldIndex == 0) && !(o.SegmentSequence==0 && o.FieldIndex==1))
                .ToList();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid HL7 syntax.");
        }
    }

    public static Func<Field, bool> Locate(string descriptor)
    {
        if(descriptor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(descriptor);
        Action throwSyntaxException = () => {
            var msg = string.Format("Invalid descriptor syntax: '{0}'", descriptor);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
        };

        var elements = descriptor.Split(':');
        if(elements.Length != 2) throwSyntaxException();

        int ndx;
        if(!int.TryParse(elements[1], out ndx)) throwSyntaxException();

        return (field) => field.SegmentId == elements[0] && field.FieldIndex == ndx;
    }
}
```